# Amazon lex chatbot isn't interpreting the HTML

Tags: chatbot, amazon-lex

I am trying to print the link in response in amazon lex chatbot integrated with facebook, however, it showing the all raw link in response. It's not interpreting the HTML code.

This is my code:

```
import json
import datetime
import time
def validate(slots):
    if not slots["Invite"]:
        return {
            "isValid": False,
            "violatedSlot": "Invite",
        }
    return {"isValid": True}
    
def convert_link_to_html(url):
    return f'<a href="{url}">click here</a>'
    


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # print(event)
    slots = event["sessionState"]["intent"]["slots"]
    intent = event["sessionState"]["intent"]["name"]
    print(event["invocationSource"])
    print(slots)
    print(intent)
    validation_result = validate(event["sessionState"]["intent"]["slots"])

    if event["invocationSource"] == "DialogCodeHook":
        if not validation_result["isValid"]:
            response = {
                "sessionState": {
                    "dialogAction": {
                        "slotToElicit": validation_result["violatedSlot"],
                        "type": "ElicitSlot"
                    },
                    "intent": {"name": intent, "slots": slots},
                }
            }
        else:
            response = {
                "sessionState": {
                    "dialogAction": {"type": "Delegate"},
                    "intent": {"name": intent, "slots": slots},
                },
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "PlainText",
                        "content": "Thanks, I have placed your reservation",
                    }
                ]
            }
        return response

    link='https://www.google.com/'
    if event["invocationSource"] == "FulfillmentCodeHook":
        response = {
            "sessionState": {
                "dialogAction": {"type": "Close"},
                "intent": {"name": intent, "slots": slots, "state": "Fulfilled"},
            },
            "messages": [
                {
                    "contentType": "CustomPayload",
                    "content": "Thanks, I have placed your reservation" +convert_link_to_html(link),
                }
            ]
        }
    return response
```

This is my response:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Siaiz.png)

Could you please help me to print this response?

Thanks, I have placed your reservation click here.

So, when i click on Click here then it would open new webpage.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to integrate with facebook but it still showing the same response as in amazon lex chatbot console.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).